# True/false question: limit of absolute function

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

I have this true/false question that I think is true because I can not really find a counterexample but I find it hard to really prove it. I tried with the regular epsilon/delta definition of a limit but I can't find a closing proof. Anyone that

> If $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}  | f(x) | = | A |$ then $ \lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = A  $

Comment: You should try some *negative* numbers as well...

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ need not even exist. For example, take $f(x)=\cases{1,&$x$ rational\cr -1, &$x$ irrational }.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that it isn't true. As a concrete example, $f(x) = x.$ Then $\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| = a = |-a|$ if $a > 0$ but $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \not = -a.$ The issue pops up in that $|A|$ can be either $A$ or $-A$ depending on the sign of $A.$

Comment: How could I not see that! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ be constant $1$ and $A:=-1$.